# Mount SMB share without 2GB filesize limit in OSX Lion

Tags: osx-lion, samba, smb, smbfs

I want to mount a network attached drive onto OSX Lion with Samba.

Usually I do this in Finder with "Go>Connect to Server" and type "smb://192.xxx.xx.xxx" in the Server Adress field, however doing this i ran into a problem with transfering files larger than 2GB (SMB limit).

To bypass this issue I need to mount the drive with LFS (Large File Support), there are many posts online that show how to do this in terminal in Linux, but I cannot find nowhere how to do it in OSX. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Lion, OS X does not come with Samba, but with another implementation of SMB/CIFS.

[OS X documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man8/mount_smbfs.8.html) does not have an option for large file.

You perhaps simply need to update your OS X installation. I have OS X Mountain Lion, and files of 3GB are copied over SMB without trouble. Either you need to upgrade to Mountain Lion or to a newer Lion release.

Other possibility, your server does not support large file and needs an upgrade.